# Make equilateral triangle from two hexagons

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Given two congruent regular hexagons, we should partition them into a total of $n$ pieces. What is the smallest value of $n$  so that the $n$ pieces together can be formed into an equilateral triangle?

If we start with only one hexagon, it is possible to use [five pieces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579630/cutting-a-hexagon-to-make-an-equilateral-triangle). But we can't combine an equilateral triangle and a hexagon, or two equilateral triangles together. In addition, from a regular hexagon we can make two equilateral triangles by cutting segments $AC,CE,EA$ if the hexagon is $ABCDEF$.

Comment: Which evidence do you have that this is even possible?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, it's an old theorem that any two simple polygons of equal area are equidecomposable.  So start with the equilateral triangle and first cut it in half.  Then decompose each half to produce a hexagon.  That shows it's possible.  (Of course Aretino's answer does better, in terms of fewer pieces.)

Comment: @BarryCipra: When I commented, the question was asking specifically for a decomposition into $6$ parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Six pieces: green hexagon is cut into five pieces and red one is a single piece:

[image]

Comment: Nice construction! But can you prove $6$ is the *least* number of pieces for which a construction is possible?

Comment: @BarryCipra Of course I cannot: this is just the best I can do at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another six piece dissection.

Two equally sized regular hexagons can be cut into two and four pieces as follows:
[image]

The six pieces can then be reassembled to form a single equilateral triangle as follows:
[image]

Like @Aretino, I cannot prove 6 is the least number of pieces needed for such a construction.